# Applying AAE changes in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, ios, photography

I've imported thousands of photos from my phone over the past 10 years, many of which have an AAE file including the edits I've made whilst on my phone, but I've never figured out how to apply the changes to my photos.

Is there any application I can just point at my photos directory and it'll go through and apply all of the changes in the AAE files please?

Thank you

Comment: [How to open Apple iOS .AAE file?](https://superuser.com/q/1281598/903157)

Comment: Thank you, I did read that before posting but unfortunately it doesn't help me - I don't have the IMG_E imports, and I can't go back and make the edits in Snapseed rather than iOS any more either :(

Comment: Based on what I'm reading online, there may not be any programs for non-Apple devices to process aae files.  They seem to be xml files, so you might be able to figure out how to parse them to duplicate the edits.

Comment: Thank you :) I think my best option unfortunately is to delete my AAE files (I have almost 1,000!) and just manually make changes to the photos as and when I open them again. Will definitely avoid using the iOS built in Photos app for editing photos in the future, and use Snapseed instead. Thanks again